# What is the meaning of the EchoNest API's getTimbre vector?

Tags: echonest

The [EchoNest
 Analyzer Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160528174915/http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/_static/AnalyzeDocumentation.pdf) states the following regarding timbre:

> *timbre* is the quality of a musical note or sound that distinguishes
>   different types of musical instruments, or voices. It is a complex
>   notion also referred to as sound color, texture, or tone quality, and
>   is derived from the shape of a segment’s spectro-temporal surface,
>   independently of pitch and loudness. The Echo Nest Analyzer’s timbre
>   feature is a vector that includes 12 unbounded values roughly centered
>   around 0. Those values are high level abstractions of the spectral
>   surface, ordered by degree of importance. For completeness however,
>   the first dimension represents the average loudness of the segment;
>   second emphasizes brightness; third is more closely correlated to the
>   flatness of a sound; fourth to sounds with a stronger attack; etc. See
>   an image below representing the 12 basis functions (i.e. template
>   segments). The actual timbre of the segment is best described as a
>   linear combination of these 12 basis functions weighted by the
>   coefficient values: timbre = c1 x b1 + c2 x b2 + ... + c12 x b12,
>   where c1 to c12 represent the 12 coefficients and b1 to b12 the 12
>   basis functions as displayed below. Timbre vectors are best used in
>   comparison with each other.
>   [image]

My understanding is that the `b` vector (`{b1...b12}`) is what is being returned by your API's `getTimbre` method. But then where are the `{c1...c12}` coefficients coming from? I don't understand how to acquire a scalar timbre from a vector timbre (primarily because your analysis API is closed source). Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that answers on this website come from volunteers. To get official support for the library, you need to contact the publisher directly.

b1 … b12 is *not* the result of the audio analysis, it is merely descriptive of what the analysis does. They are fixed constants as shown in the diagram:

[image]

The vector of scalars c1 … c12 is what the analyzer produces. Of course, the sound cannot be perfectly described by only 12 numbers. Multiplying the scalars by the functions won't reproduce the original music because there's not enough data there; it's only an approximation. Possibly, though, you'll get a similar "mood" from each segment, so it could be interesting to try and listen.

Comment: Got that, but if say i want to ascertain how many instruments are there, how does this help ? (correlations between these vectors)? I contacted the publisher, lets see.

Comment: @ArunavSanyal You never mentioned counting how many instruments, and that's a much harder problem. The analysis is looking at all the sound as a whole.

Comment: one example. But timbral information is the best way to go I suppose.