# EchoNest 12 dimensional vector of timbre - meaning of each element?

Tags: echonest

This is not the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292855/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-echonest-apis-gettimbre-vector)

The EchoNest Analyzer Documentation states the following regarding timbre:

> The Echo Nest Analyzer’s timbre feature is a vector that includes 12
>   unbounded values roughly centered around 0.
>
> Those values are high level abstractions of the spectral surface,
>   ordered by degree of importance.
>
> For completeness however, **the first dimension represents the average
>   loudness of the segment; second emphasizes brightness; third is more
>   closely correlated to the flatness of a sound; fourth to sounds with a
>   stronger attack; etc**

I am looking for the **rest of the list..** what is the high level meaning of each dimension.

Have not found it anywhere, and can not think of a way to check the meaning myself (using other music analysis or ml clustring).